# quotes are still shown when I use print in python+jupyter

Tags: python, string, printing, jupyter

A simple code like this:

```
print("sfjeorf",4,"fefa",5,)
```

I run this in jupyter, using python. And the result is:

```
('sfjeorf', '4', 'fefa', '5')
```

[image]

What I should do to get rid of the quotes and the brackets so that the result is shown like:

```
sfjeorf4fefa5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using Python 2, which doesn't take `()` around the arguments, so it thinks you are printing a tuple.  Use the following or switch to Python 3, where `print` became a function instead of a statement.

```
print "sfjeorf",4,"fefa",5
```

Getting rid of the spaces to get your requested output is trickier.  Easiest in Python 2 is to import the print function implementation:

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> print("sfjeorf",4,"fefa",5)
sfjeorf 4 fefa 5
>>> print("sfjeorf",4,"fefa",5,sep='')
sfjeorf4fefa5
```

Answer (score 0):

In this kind of situation I prefer to use [string.format()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#format) to have more control of the output. Take a look on how the code would be:

```
>>> print('{}{}{}{}'.format("sfjeorf",4,"fefa",5,))
sfjeorf4fefa5
```